# Neo4J: query optimisation/model validation

Tags: neo4j, cypher

New to Neo4J so apologies in advance if I am doing things horribly wrong. I am trying to show user articles in which they could be interested in based on the categories they have selected and tags they have liked independently.
My model in Neo4j is something like this

```
(:USER)-[:LIKES]->(:TAG)
(:ARTICLE)-[:PUBLISHED_BY]->(:PROVIDER)
(:ARTICLE)-[:HAS_CATEGORY]->(:CATEGORY)
(:USER)-[:DISLIKES]-(:ARTICLE)
(:USER)-[:INTERESTED_IN]->(:CATEGORY)
```

When I try to run the following query to get the desired results...I get them but the query is taking 16-18 seconds to execute.

```
MATCH (u:USER {id: $userid})-[:LIKES]->(t:TAG) 
WITH u,t, collect(t.name) as tags 
UNWIND tags as tag with u,tag 
MATCH (c:CATEGORY)<-[*]-(a:ARTICLE)-[pub:PUBLISHED_BY]->(p:PROVIDER) 
WHERE a.keywords contains tag OR c.id in $categoryArray 
  AND NOT (u)-[:DISLIKES]->(a) 
RETURN DISTINCT a.id AS id, a.title AS title, pub.pubDate 
ORDER BY pub.pubDate DESC LIMIT 250
```

Is there a faster and better way to get the desired results?
Note: I am using Neo4j 3.4.1 version on ubuntu machine with page-cache: 512mb and MIN & MAX heap size: 1500mb

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if in your model articles are connected to tags.

This bit: `a.keywords contains tag` is not index supported, so it will lead to a full scan.

Also, from categories to articles might be a long chain, so add a rel-type there and add an upper limit. It might be better to check found articles against categories.

```
MATCH (u:USER {id: $userid})-[:LIKES]->(tag:TAG) 
MATCH (a:ARTICLE)-[:HAS_TAG]->(tag)
WITH distinct u, a
WHERE any(c IN categories WHERE NOT shortestPath((c)<-[:IN_CATEGORY*]-(a)) IS NULL)
  AND NOT (u)-[:DISLIKES]->(a) 
MATCH (a)-[pub:PUBLISHED_BY]->(p:PROVIDER) 
RETURN DISTINCT a.id AS id, a.title AS title, pub.pubDate 
ORDER BY pub.pubDate DESC LIMIT 250
```

Also check the query plan with `PROFILE` to see any bottlenecks or unindexed fields (you can expand the boxes with the double arrow in the lower right corner)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Michael I understand that having tags as separate nodes related to articles would make the search faster but the following query has brought down the search time from 16-18 seconds to 3-4 seconds at the moment

```
MATCH (u:USER {id: $userId})-[:INTERESTED_IN]->(c:CATEGORY)<-[*]-(a:ARTICLE)[pub:PUBLISHED_BY]->(p:PROVIDER) WHERE NOT (u)-[:DISLIKES]->(a) RETURN DISTINCT a.id, a.title, pub.pubDate ORDER BY pub.pubDate DESC LIMIT 150 UNION MATCH (u:USER {id: $userId})-[:LIKES]->(t:TAG) WITH u, t, collect(t.name) AS tags UNWIND tags AS tag MATCH (a:ARTICLE)-[pub:PUBLISHED_BY]-(:PROVIDER) WHERE a.keywords CONTAINS tag AND NOT (u)-[:DISLIKES]->(a) RETURN DISTINCT a.id, a.title, pub.pubDate ORDER BY pub.pubDate DESC LIMIT 150
```